# How can I group API results by an id in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, grouping

I got information from an API returning places for each specific location in each of the rows in my dataframe table. I then transformed this information into another dataframe table. Now I'm wondering how I can create an id for the 2nd table that groups each result returned by the id in the first.

My API results:

```json
[{'results': [{'location': {'address': '150 Greenwood Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'Dundas St E',
     'formatted_address': '150 Greenwood Ave (Dundas St E), Toronto ON M4L 2R1',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 2R1',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Leslieville Farmers Market',
    'rating': 9.1},
   {'location': {'address': '1001 Eastern Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'Woodfield Rd',
     'formatted_address': '1001 Eastern Ave (Woodfield Rd), Toronto ON M4L 1A8',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 1A8',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Rorschach Brewing',
    'rating': 8.7},
   {'location': {'address': '1483 Queen St E',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '1483 Queen St E, Toronto ON M4L 1E2',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 1E2',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Chick-N-Joy',
    'rating': 7.6},
   {'location': {'address': '1592 Queen St E',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '1592 Queen St E, Toronto ON M4L 1G1',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 1G1',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Velotique',
    'rating': 7.4},
   {'location': {'address': '6 Coxwell Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'Queen',
     'formatted_address': '6 Coxwell Ave (Queen), Toronto ON M4L 3A7',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 3A7',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'O Sushi',
    'rating': 7.5},
   {'location': {'address': 'Queen St',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'at Kingston Rd',
     'formatted_address': 'Queen St (at Kingston Rd), Toronto ON M4L 1G7',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 1G7',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Woodbine Park',
    'rating': 8.5},
   {'location': {'address': '1374 Queen St E',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'at Greenwood Ave',
     'formatted_address': '1374 Queen St E (at Greenwood Ave), Toronto ON M4L 1C9',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 1C9',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'The Sidekick',
    'rating': 8.8},
   {'location': {'address': '1636 Queen St E',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'btwn Coxwell Ave. & Kingston Rd.',
     'formatted_address': '1636 Queen St E (btwn Coxwell Ave. & Kingston Rd.), Toronto ON M4L 1G3',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 1G3',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': "The Burger's Priest",
    'rating': 7.6},
   {'location': {'address': '1646 Queen St E',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'at Eastern Ave,',
     'formatted_address': '1646 Queen St E (at Eastern Ave,), Toronto ON M4L 1G3',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 1G3',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Casa Di Giorgios',
    'rating': 7.4},
   {'location': {'address': '73 Coxwell Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'Dundas St & Coxwell St',
     'formatted_address': '73 Coxwell Ave (Dundas St & Coxwell St), Toronto ON M4L 3B1',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M4L 3B1',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'British Style Fish & Chips',
    'rating': 7.6}],
  'context': {'geo_bounds': {'circle': {'center': {'latitude': 43.665269,
      'longitude': -79.319796},
     'radius': 1000}}}},
 {'results': [{'location': {'address': '31 Powerhouse St',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'Lansdowne Ave',
     'formatted_address': '31 Powerhouse St (Lansdowne Ave), Toronto ON M6H 0C7',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 0C7',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': "Balzac's Coffee Roasters",
    'rating': 8.4},
   {'location': {'address': '330 Geary Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'at Lightbourn Ave.',
     'formatted_address': '330 Geary Ave (at Lightbourn Ave.), Toronto ON M6H 2C7',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 2C7',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Rehearsal Factory',
    'rating': 6.7},
   {'location': {'address': '1200 Lansdowne Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '1200 Lansdowne Ave, Toronto ON M6H 3Z8',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 3Z8',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Earlscourt Park Off-Leash Area',
    'rating': 6.2},
   {'location': {'address': '229 Geary Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'at Dufferin St',
     'formatted_address': '229 Geary Ave (at Dufferin St), Toronto ON M6H 2C1',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 2C1',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'The Greater Good Bar',
    'rating': 8.9},
   {'location': {'address': '1311 Saint Clair Ave W',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '1311 Saint Clair Ave W, Toronto ON M6E 1C2',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6E 1C2',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Tre Mari Bakery',
    'rating': 9.0},
   {'location': {'address': '1200 Lansdowne Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '1200 Lansdowne Ave, Toronto ON M6H 3Z8',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 3Z8',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Earlscourt Park',
    'rating': 7.5},
   {'location': {'address': '1359 Davenport Rd',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '1359 Davenport Rd, Toronto ON M6H 2H5',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 2H5',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'The Sovereign',
    'rating': 7.3},
   {'location': {'address': '217 Geary Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '217 Geary Ave, Toronto ON M6H 2C1',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 2C1',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Parallel',
    'rating': 8.2},
   {'location': {'address': '1256 Saint Clair Ave W',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': 'at Boon Ave.',
     'formatted_address': '1256 Saint Clair Ave W (at Boon Ave.), Toronto ON M6E 1B9',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6E 1B9',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'Rio 40 Restaurant',
    'rating': 8.4},
   {'location': {'address': '229 Geary Ave',
     'country': 'CA',
     'cross_street': '',
     'formatted_address': '229 Geary Ave, Toronto ON M6H 2C1',
     'locality': 'Toronto',
     'postcode': 'M6H 2C1',
     'region': 'ON'},
    'name': 'North Of Brooklyn Pizzeria',
    'rating': 7.3}],
  'context': {'geo_bounds': {'circle': {'center': {'latitude': 43.67142,
      'longitude': -79.445947},
     'radius': 1000}}}},
```

Like I want result#1 to be id 1, result#2 to be id 2.

My first table:

[image: Table_1]

Second table:

[image: Table_2]

I have tried to do something like this:

```
id = 0
for res in info:
    id+=1
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                  'id': id,
                  'name' : names,
                  'rating' : ratings,
                  'location' : locations
                  
                  })
```

But this just returns the same id for each row.

I am expecting something like:

| id | place |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | place_1_in location_1 |
| 1 | place_2_in location_1 |
| 2 | place_1_in location_2 |
| 3 | place_2_in location_3 |

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need an ID or can i just be the `'context': {'geo_bounds': ...}` since that is unique for each result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using `pd.json_normalize` where `data` is your API result

```
# normalize the json data from the API
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'results', [['context', 'geo_bounds', 'circle', 'center', 'latitude'],
                                         ['context', 'geo_bounds', 'circle', 'center', 'longitude']])
# groupby the geo_bounds and get the number of groups
df['ID'] = df.groupby(['context.geo_bounds.circle.center.latitude',
                       'context.geo_bounds.circle.center.longitude']).ngroup()+1

# you can then keep the columns that you need
print(df[['ID', 'name', 'rating', 'location.formatted_address']])

    ID                            name  rating 
0    1      Leslieville Farmers Market     9.1   
1    1               Rorschach Brewing     8.7   
2    1                     Chick-N-Joy     7.6   
3    1                       Velotique     7.4   
4    1                         O Sushi     7.5   
5    1                   Woodbine Park     8.5   
6    1                    The Sidekick     8.8   
7    1             The Burger's Priest     7.6   
8    1                Casa Di Giorgios     7.4   
9    1      British Style Fish & Chips     7.6   
10   2        Balzac's Coffee Roasters     8.4   
11   2               Rehearsal Factory     6.7   
12   2  Earlscourt Park Off-Leash Area     6.2   
13   2            The Greater Good Bar     8.9   
14   2                 Tre Mari Bakery     9.0   
15   2                 Earlscourt Park     7.5   
16   2                   The Sovereign     7.3   
17   2                        Parallel     8.2   
18   2               Rio 40 Restaurant     8.4   
19   2      North Of Brooklyn Pizzeria     7.3
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This helps a lot but I am getting an id of 3 instead of 1 for the first result, 5 for the second, etc, not sure why.